# how to serialize a class without base class in protobuf C#

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net, base-class

I have class that extend DictionaryBase class.
when serialize this class with protobuf give below exception:

```
Repeated data (a list, collection, etc) has inbuilt behaviour and cannot be subclassed
```

this is my code :

```
[protoContract]
public class myClass :DictionaryBase
{
    [protomember(1)]
    public int temp {get; set;}
}
```

DictionaryBase class is in the System.Collenctions

how can not Serialize base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `IgnoreListHandling=true` to the `[ProtoContract]`. However! This will mean it ignores the dictionary contents and **only** serializes `temp`. Like `XmlSerializer`, to protobuf-net, a type is *either* a collection *or* a leaf; never both.